# tr method causing error

Tags: pyqgis

Can somebody explain the following line:

```
self.menu = self.tr(u'&TestPlugin')
```

I don't understand what is in the parentheses: the small u and the need for the apostrophes.
This line was created automatically in the plugin builder and while it works fine in pycharm it causes an error in pydev and therefore not enabling me to debug.The error states:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Encountered "\'&TestPlugin\'" at line 72, column 30. Was expecting one of:     "(" ...     ")" ...     "[" ...     "," ...     "." ...     "+" ...     "-" ...     "*" ...     "/" ...     "//" ...     "<<" ...     ">>" ...     "%" ...     "^" ...     "|" ...     "&" ...     ">" ...     "<" ...     "==" ...     "<=" ...     ">=" ...     "!=" ...     "or" ...     "and" ...     "not" ...     "is" ...     "in" ...     "if" ...     "for" ...     "," ...     "," ...         TestPlugin.py   /test2/test - Copy  line 71 Problem
```

Is there a way to make pycharm ignore the error so I can continue debugging? I tried adding:

```
#@UnusedVariable
```

At the end of the line but it didn't work.

Perhaps there is something wrong with the interpreter Or I need to add an import?

Comment: `self.tr` means translate (usually) in pyqgis, `u'SomeString'` means a unicode string (as it's a string, the apostrophes are required) and the `&` ampersand character is probably a menu accelerator/shortcut key.

Comment: @Luke, I think that comment could qualify as an answer.

Comment: @fetzer it's not a complete answer, I didn't address the error.